# Include Git tag (or SVN revision) in Arduino sketch?

Tags: programming, sketch, version-control

Is there any way to get the current Git tag/commit identifier into an Arduino sketch binary?

For normal desktop program development, you can pull some tricks with the Makefile (as pointed out in [this StackExchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6526504/1480315)). However, there is no Makefile for an Arduino sketch. Right?

I could make a batch file that I run before every compile, but there is the very real possibility I will forget to run it, and incorrect version information is worse than no version information.

At the moment, I am using the preprocessor macros `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` to try and identify what version is running on the board. This works, but tracking backwards from a compile date/time to a source control commit is more guesswork than anything.

Comment: You could ditch the Arduino IDE and go for a [Makefile-based development](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile).

Comment: `tracking backwards from a compile date/time to a source control commit is more guesswork than anything` - why? Commits have the date in them.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I think that is what I am looking for! I will give that a try. If you post that as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Cellie's answer, I investigated further and found a similar
method that can be implemented using the regular interface of the
Arduino IDE.

It appears that GitHub user Wackerbarth, while facing the very same
problem, opened [an issue on the Arduino bug tracker](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/2732):

> It would be very useful to be able to add a recipe to the platform
>   specification that is executed at the start of the build process.
>   (pre-build)
>
> In particular, my use case is to generate version strings which will
>   be incorporated in the Rom image based on information extracted from a
>   SCM repository.

He went on to submit [a pull request](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/2738) for adding “hooks” to the
build process, which made it to release 1.6.2. See the documentation on
these [Pre and post build hooks](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5-3rd-party-Hardware-specification#pre-and-post-build-hooks-since-ide-165).

Here is how you can use this feature for including git commit
information into your program (tested on Arduino 1.8.5 / Ubuntu 16.04):

1. Save the following file under the name `make-git-version`, somewhere
   in your `PATH`, and make it executable:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Go to the source directory.
[ -n "$1" ] && cd "$1" || exit 1

# Build a version string with git.
version=$(git describe --tags --always --dirty 2> /dev/null)

# If this is not a git repository, fallback to the compilation date.
[ -n "$version" ] || version=$(date -I)

# Save this in git-version.h.
echo "#define GIT_VERSION \"$version\"" > $2/sketch/git-version.h
```

2. Locate the file named `platform.txt` in the Arduino installation
   directory (currently in `arduino-1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr` for the
   AVR boards). In the same directory, create a file named
   `platform.local.txt` with the following content:

```
recipe.hooks.sketch.prebuild.1.pattern=make-git-version "{build.source.path}" "{build.path}"
```

3. In your sketch, include `"git-version.h"` and use it like so:

```c++
#include "git-version.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("This is version " GIT_VERSION);
}
```

4. Create an empty file in your sketch directory named `git-version.h`.

Note that the `git-version.h` in the current directory is only needed
for the first compilation. The real `git-version.h` will be in the
temporary build directory.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with Arduino (ESP32) versioning also.
To make it somewhat more practical and less error prone I made some scripts to assist this process.

Using these scripts is as easy as adding them to your sketch folder and adding

```
#include "gitTagVersion.h"
...
Serial.println( sketchVersion );
```

to your Arduino sketch.
That is all that is needed.

The output in the example above will be something like v1.0.0-3-gab3fb04.

That breaks down to tag `v1.0.0`, we had `3` commits since that tag, at commit `ab3fb04`.

HOW TO INSTALL AND USE?

There are 2 scripts involved, the first script is a replacement for the Arduino  Verify button.
Save it as verify.sh:

```
echo "const char * sketchVersion = \"$(git describe --tags --always --dirty)\";" > gitTagVersion.h
~/arduino-1.8.5/arduino --verify test.ino
rm gitTagVersion.h
```

And the second script replaces the Upload button.
Save it as upload.sh:

```
echo "const char * sketchVersion = \"$(git describe --tags --always --dirty)\";" > gitTagVersion.h
~/arduino-1.8.5/arduino --upload test.ino --pref custom_DebugLevel=esp32_none
rm gitTagVersion.h
```

Some things to note about these scripts:

- The scripts REPLACE the buttons.
  You won’t be able to use the buttons anymore, as these buttons don’t
  generate the necessary version info from git.

  Using them will result in this error:

  > fatal error: gitTagVersion.h:    No such file or directory
- The scripts are hardcoded to use Arduino 1.8.5 and have to be updated
  if you update your Arduino IDE.
- These script only work in Linux with a vanilla Arduino install.
- If you use Windows, or are on a Mac the scripts will not work.
- To change the debug output (using the LOGx_ESP macros) on ESP32
  builds, change the custom_DebugLevel in the Upload script to
  esp32_xxxx, where xxxx is none, info, error, debug or verbose.

I posted this also on my [blog](http://wasietsmet.nl/arduino/add-git-tag-and-version-number-to-an-arduino-sketch/) and [esp32.com](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=5213)

Comment: I would drop the `-n` in `echo -n '";'`: it is customary in Unixland that text files (specially source code) end with a line feed. Also, you could replace the first three lines of each of those scripts by `echo "const char * sketchVersion = \"$(git describe --tags --always --dirty)\";" > gitTagVersion.h`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Platformio, add this in platformio.ini file

```
build_flags = 
    !echo '-D GIT_VERSION=\\"'$(git rev-parse HEAD)'\\"'
```

And use it like this:

```
Serial.printf("Firmware version: %s\n", GIT_VERSION);
```

Check out relevant docs:
http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/section_env_build.html#dynamic-build-flags

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem and based on the previous answers I wrote this [script](https://github.com/fabiuz7/git-describe-arduino) for Arduino IDE. I'm using it successfully on different OSs for many months to now. In the repository, you can find the instructions to install it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the commit ID would prove. I use git for source control for my Arduino sketches, but a particular upload might be halfway between the previous commit and the next one. That is, the code on the board might not match any particular commit.

The date/time would at least identify approximately where in the commit stream the code is.

A possibility would be to run a cron job that periodically (say, every minute) updates a .h file with the current commit ID from the branch, and include that in the sketch.

Comment: It is true that you can be compiling with a dirty working copy, but at least you know for sure what commit you started with for that firmware. With just a date, you can't know for sure which branch was compiled, especially if multiple branches were updated at about the same time. And finally, using date/time leads to problems with time zones, lending even more ambiguity to exactly what was compiled.

Comment: If you say so. A "dirty working copy" could be anything. I'm not sure what the original commit ID proves. `using date/time leads to problems with time zones` - how many time zones are you in? I'm in one, personally.

Comment: I still work with friends from college, and we now live in different states. The time zone thing has bit me in the past, I'm not trying to be a jerk or anything. Knowing the original commit ID lets me know what branch the sketch came from, at least. I do agree that a dirty working copy can indicate anything, but generally it is close to the base commit.

Comment: People *have* made makefiles to compiler their Arduino stuff. I can't think of any really simple way of doing it, short of my suggestion of a cron job to update a .h file regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Edgar's Bash script, I wrote a Windows **Batch** script do almost the same in adition to copying HEX file from the temp build directory to the project directory and insert commit hash, date, branch name and tag to it's name. I wrote a short article on [how to use GIT to manage firmware versions](https://atadiat.com/en/e-how-to-use-git-to-manage-firmware-versions/).

```
:: How to use:
:: Add this file to you Arduino project directory and add the following line to platform.txt from Arduino core files
:: recipe.hooks.sketch.prebuild.1.pattern = {build.source.path}\fw_ver.bat GIT {build.path} {build.source.path}
:: recipe.hooks.objcopy.postobjcopy.2.pattern = {build.source.path}\fw_ver.bat SAVE {build.path} {build.source.path}

@echo off

:: arg1 -> "GIT" print version, commit number, brnach name and commit date , "SAVE" copy the .hex file from temp build directory to project directory
set arg1=%1
:: arg2 -> path to temp build directory
set arg2=%2
:: arg3 -> path to project source files
set arg3=%3

cd %arg3%

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`git describe --match^=NeVeRmAtCh --always --abbrev^=7`) DO (
SET commit=%%F
)

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`git show -s --format^=%%cd --date^=format:%%y_%%m_%%d %commit%`) DO (
SET date=%%F
)

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`) DO (
SET branch=%%F
)

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`git describe --abbrev^=0`) DO (
SET ver=%%F
)
::Export to version.h
ECHO #define FW_VER "%ver%" > version.h
ECHO #define COMMIT_NUMBER "%commit%" >> version.h
ECHO #define COMMIT_DATE "%date%" >> version.h
ECHO #define COMMIT_BRANCH "%branch%" >> version.h

IF "%arg1%"=="GIT" (
@echo on
@echo version:%ver% Commit:%commit% Branch:%branch% Date:%date% 
@echo off
)
IF "%arg1%"=="SAVE" (
@echo on
@echo Save fw_%ver%_%branch%_%date%_%commit%.hex to %arg3%
COPY "%arg2%\fw.ino.hex" "fw_%ver%_%branch%_%date%_%commit%.hex"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do Makefile-like tricks, one possibility is to use a
Makefile-based workflow instead of the Arduino IDE. There are a few
generic Arduino Makefiles floating around the Web. One quite popular is
[Sudar Muthu's Arduino
Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile). With it, you just
write a small per-project Makefile that sets a few variables and then
includes the generic Makefile. There is one limitation with this
approach though: the Arduino IDE normally modifies your .ino file before
submitting it to the compiler, in two ways:

1. It #includes <Arduino.h>
2. It writes prototypes near the beginning of the program for every
   function you define.

Sudar Muthu's Makefile does include Arduino.h (it does not touch your
code, using instead the `-include` gcc option), but it does *not* write
the function prototypes for you. It is thus not 100% compatible with the
Arduino IDE.

Another possibility would be to completely write yourself a Makefile
that calls [Arduino
Builder](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder). This should be
100% compatible with the IDE.